# Deforming the initial cube by mouse

Tags: edit-mode

I would like to move one or two vertices of the initial cube in Blender so that it becomes a bit rhomboidal (deformed) by dragging the captured vertex with the mouse. I cannot find the right place in Blender to
play with deforming the cube. More specifically I need that the cube remains as a whole, just deformed. I have found something similar to this in the l.h.s. but not quite what I need.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a tool that does this for you, but you can manipulate the shape yourself. Here's how I would do it:

1. go to edit mode (either press <kbd>Tab</kbd> or go to the left corner, change it from *Object Mode* to *Edit mode*) you know that you are in *Edit Mode* if you see the vertices of the cube as dots
   [image: change from object to edit mode]
2. now select 4 vertices while holding <kbd>Shift</kbd> (the selected vertices appear orange and the one you selected last is white)
   [image: four selected vertices in orange]
3. press <kbd>S</kbd> (for changing the scale) and then press <kbd>Y</kbd> (to scale it along the Y-axis, but you could also press <kbd>X</kbd> to scale it along the X-axis or <kbd>Z</kbd>)
   [image: deformed cube]
4. to scale it you just need to move your mouse in the direction you want to scale it
5. if you are still in the scaling mode (you see a dotted black line coming from the center of your object), you can switch between the axes by pressing <kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>Y</kbd> or <kbd>Z</kbd> and continue scaling along them

Hope this helps

(if you just want to move one vertex at a time, just click on the one you want to move and then press <kbd>G</kbd> to move it in space or <kbd>G</kbd> and then <kbd>Z</kbd> to move it along the Z-axis)